# Pivot table creation failing with runtime error 1004

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

This code used to work on office 365. I am now working on office 2016 and I am getting a runtime error on the final line. The input to this is:

```
'Create a Pivot table called pt commission on sheet "Pivot Table" from the data on sheet2
Call ptSettings.CreatePivotTable("Pivot Table", Sheet2, "ptCommission")
```

The sub that is throwing the error on the final line is:

```
Sub CreatePivotTable(ptSheet As String, dSheet As Worksheet, ptName As String)

'Creates a pivottable called ptName on sheets(ptSheet) with the data from dsheet

Dim ptCache As PivotCache
Dim ptTable As pivotTable
Dim ptRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Worksheets(ptSheet).Delete
Sheets.Add before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = ptSheet
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

lastRow = dSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
lastCol = dSheet.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set ptRange = dSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(lastRow, lastCol + 1)

Set ptCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=ptRange)

Set ptTable = ptCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=Sheets(ptSheet).Cells(3, 1), TableName:=ptName)

End Sub
```

Comment: what is the value of lastRow, lastCol, and ptRange?

Comment: lastRow is 93, lastCol is 21 and ptRange is the data on "dSheet".

Answer (score 0):

Cheers for taking a look guys!

Just found out what was happening. There was data in the second row making the lastCol be higher than it needed to be. Then when I tried to create a pivot table from that range it threw the error because ptRange didnt have column headings.

I only realised after I tried running vs stepping through it and it came out with a different error.. Oh VBA.